# Why does installation of 22.04.2 LTS on my hard drive not tell me when it has finished installing

Tags: system-installation

I installed (or tried to at least) 22.04.2 LTS and it left the cursor swirling for 5 hours without stopping or telling me anything about the progress or end of the installation. I finally stopped  the computer and found it had installed but left my hard drive encripted with a password that I didn't have. Now I'm installing it again and the cursor is just swirling away again. How long should it take to format a 500 G drive? When can I assume the installation is finished?

Comment: You've not told us which Ubuntu 22.04 LTS product you're using, as different installers are available (`subiquity` by Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Server, `ubiquity` by Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Desktop etc) thus we can't provide much currently with the install. As for how long a disk format will take, it'll depend on many factors you didn't provide (file-system? if verification of sectors is being done or only file-system table is being newly created & populated, drive health & type etc). You can read logs for clues (*I'd explore system logs at text terminal*) but we don't know what product/installer you're using

Comment: If you are install Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Desktop; you're installing with a *deprecated* kernel and I'd have considered using 22.04.3 media; if using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Server, the installer can be updated prior to install but as it'll default to the GA kernel stack anyway; that kernel is *outdated* but still *supported*. If your hardware is new, you may have been better using the updated media (*rather than media with revoked keys*)